# React useEffect stops working (populating state) on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a dictionary and using my API to fetch the words of a particular user.
In a nutshell, I have one useEffect that fetches user's words (with an argument *wordText* which is an input value of a search bar - I need it to see if a word is already present in the vocabulary). I then render the words with words.map.
The problem is that when I reload the page I get *words.map is not a function* error, indicating that either *words* is empty or is not an array. The page renders the words only if I first comment out the useEffect, load the page and then bring useEffect back.

<< I removed all unrelated code >>

There is WordsBlock definition with *words* and *wordText* defined:

```
const WordsBlock = ({id}) => {
    const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
    const [wordText, setWordText] = useState("");
```

The problematic useEffect with wordText as an argument. I guess this is the part that I don't fully understand. As I see it - on the reload of the page I have wordText empty so the case 2 is triggered and *words* is populated. There are two different responses. Everything works if I first render page and only then de-comment useEffect function

```
useEffect(() => {
            const getWordsBlock = async () => {
                const requestOptions = {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
                    },
                };
                if (wordText !== "") {
                console.log("case 1")
                const response = await fetch(`/api/vocab/${id}?word_text=${wordText}`, requestOptions);
                const data = await response.json();
                setWords(data);
                setLoaded(true)
                }
                else {
                console.log("case 2")
                const response = await fetch(`/api/vocab/${id}`, requestOptions);
                const data = await response.json();
                setWords(data);
                setLoaded(true)
                }
            }
            getWordsBlock()
        }, [wordText])
```

This is part of a return that iterates through *words*

```
return (
        <div>
            {words.map((word, index) => (
                [<div>
                    <h1 onClick={(e) => {setWordText(word.word_text); 
                        handleClick(index); translateWord(e)}}>
                        {word.word_text}
                    </h1>
                </div>
                ]
            ))} 
        </div>
    )
```

Any help is appreciated

I've tried adding loaded state and removed/added arguments in useEffect.

Comment: The error `words.map is not a function` doesn't mean that `words` is an empty array. You can map over an empty array without an error. It means that `words` is defined but it's not an array.

Comment: Also you could do everyone here a favor and only include the relevant parts of the code. All the included styles are unnecessary and just make the code harder to read. Also run your code through prettier or some kind of formatter to fix the indentation.

Comment: @I0_ol But isn't the **const[words, setWords] = useState([])** defining an array?

Comment: But you are overwriting it here: `setWords(data);` it seems that `data` is just an object not an array, can you share a print of console.log(data)?

Comment: @PauloFernando, thanks, that was the issue. I just noticed that on page mount I first get **user_id = null**  then getWordsBlock takes it as a parameter {id} and data is coming back not as an array. I fixed it just by writing **{ id != null ? (<WordsBlock id={id}/>): null}**. The part of my code that fetches user id was (and probably is) poorly written

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in the whole other part of my program that fetched current users id. While fetching user_id ({id} in the code) I was getting **null**, which was then passed to the **getWordsBlock** and the result is not an array so the ***words.map is not a function*** error was triggered.